# Which Javascript projects should I follow on Github?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to be a better Javascript coder. I've worked on Javascript on and off for 4 years, but I don't use it everyday and often I am interfacing with jQuery, rather than Javascript. That's why I feel lacking in the patterns and practices of Javascript programmers, and I am looking at the wider community for some direction and guidance.

Which projects should I dig into and learn from? Which source codes are particularly useful to read?

EDIT: I found the perfect projects. The coffeescript, underscore and docco projects seem to have particularly great source codes that are well annotated and a joy to read.

- [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/)
- [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html)
- [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html)

Comment: Why not start with jQuery itself? So get a grasp of Javascript Closures

Comment: I know about closures. I believe they are not considered best practice these days as they suffer from state pollution between tests. That is to say, private variables in closures are not testable.

Comment: This may help. [Recommended JavaScript Annotated Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840420/recommended-javascript-annotated-source-code-for-learning)

Comment: @picardo Who ever tests private variables? White code testing is doing it wrong. You should test for functionality. You should not test that the JavaScript interpreter works.

Comment: @raynos I don't use tests personally, but there is a good illustration of why this is a bad thing in this article: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/7/Writing-Testable-JavaScript

Comment: @Picardo Again I will state that testing private functions and variables is white box testing. That is doing it wrong. Treat code as a black box and test that the IO works as expected. Also how can you comment on closures being bad if you don't write tests?

Comment: @raynos: I'm having a discussion, not a debate, which seems what you think this is. Whether I use tests is besides the point. I'm going to quote what I said above: "I believe they are not considered best practice these days as they suffer from state pollution between tests." The article I linked to above explains how private variables retain the state between tests, and that is why they lead to undesirable results. It's not whether you test them directly or not, but other functions depend on them, and they persist their state between tests. That's my point.

Comment: @picardo I'm having difficulty seeing how that's different from private variables and functions in any classical OOP language. I guess the issue is using closures for private variables outside of object constructors or any cases where there is no easy way to reset state. It's an interesting point, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is on Github, but it´s not a software project. I would recommend getting yourself some coffee and read it.

[Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/)